# Balanced payment customer with multiple cards

Tags: balanced-payments

My question is:
For the same card, each time the user (owner) use it, I'll use balanced JS to tokenize it and get a different URI. Then I'll add this card to this customer on Balanced. This will cause a customer has lots of cards although they are the same one.

So what's the suggested way to implement this? Assume that I will let user types his card each time he uses it.

More background on our project:
I integrate balanced payment with my website in this way:
Front end JS will tokenize a card and pass the card URI to our backend.
Backend uses python to assign this card uri to a customer and debit at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same card each time? It's a bit of a hassle for the user to have to enter their card info for every purchase, I think.

If you really must have the user re-enter the same card info multiple times, but don't want duplicate `card` resources sitting around, you can check the `hash` attribute of the card object that was just created. If it matches the `hash` of an existing `card`, don't associate the `card` to the `customer`, but instead use the previously-existing one.

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=bash#tokenize-a-card

Comment: The user can choose not to remember his card, and in this way he might input the same card next time when making a payment. Btw, can you illustrate how to get all cards of a specific customer? I can't find this in the API doc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement in the jquery on the page where you collect the card.  If the customer has selected an existing card then the balanced.js code does not execute.

If the customer adds a new card then it is tokenized and we use the following function (in php) to add the card to the existing customer:

```
function add_card($customer_id = NULL, $card_token = NULL){
        $customer = \Balanced\Customer::get($customer_id);  
        $customer->addCard($card_token);
    }
```